# Como usar BETWEEN e o LIKE juntos numa Query?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Bom tenho uma tabela que contém algumas tabelas sendo elas ( DATA_INICIAL , DATA_FINAL ) , contudo estou tentando gerar um relatório que contenham os dados entre as datas iniciais e finais , sendo que quem coloca essas informações é o usuário ( Não é algo definido ) .

A minha busca no banco hoje só tira os dados do dia inicial e do dia final contudo quero todos os dias dentro desse intervalo , como posso realizar isso ?

Minha Consulta :

```
SQL SERVER : SELECT * FROM dbo.NOME_DA_TABELA WHERE DT_INICIAL LIKE '$data_incio' AND  DT_FINAL LIKE '$data_final'
```

- $data_inicio E $data_final são as variáveis que os usuários vão colocar num form que eu envio para essa pagina .

Comment: Você quer que os registros selecionados tenham ambas as datas DT_INICIAL e DT_FINAL entre as datas inicial e final fornecidas ou basta uma delas estar dentro do período fornecido? Creio que basta utilizar BETWEEN não entendi este LIKE.

Comment: Creio que vc quis dizer 'tabela que contám algumas colunas'. DATA_INICIAL e DATA_FINAL são de que tipo? Se você rodou e não de erro com o ilike creio que sejam varchar, nesse caso é preciso converter para data e usar o between comentado acima. coloque a ddl da tabela na pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode filtrar por registros com a data inicial igual ou maior que a informada e com a data final menor ou igual do que a selecionada pelo usuário. A consulta ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.NOME_DA_TABELA WHERE (DT_INICIAL >= '$data_incio' AND  DT_FINAL <= '$data_final')
```

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa de um `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM dbo.nome_da_tabela
 WHERE dt_inicial BETWEEN '$data_incio' AND '$data_final'
```

> [`BETWEEN`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/between-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> Especifica um intervalo a ser testado.
>
> [**Sintaxe**](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/between-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#syntax)
>
> ```
> test_expression [ NOT ] BETWEEN begin_expression AND end_expression
> ```